# Traversal on different criteria using iterator pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator, criteria, traversal

Here is the problem:

Suppose I have a huge collection of Person object, and I need to traverse the list in different ways. For example, iterate a list of people born in 1980, or live in New York City. Write down the code using ITERATOR pattern to iterate over people born in a particular year. Note that the code MUST be easy to modify or extend so that different criteria can be used.

First I used builder pattern for Person class.

```
public class Person {
//mandatory
private final String SSN;          //social security number
private final MyDate DOB;          //date of birth
private String name;               //name

//optional
private String phone;              //phone number
private USAddress address;         //home address
private USAddress workAddress;     //work address
private Set<USAddress> FVA;        //frequently visited addresses
private Set<Person> familyMembers; //family members

private Person(PersonBuilder builder){
    ...
}
```

Secondly the container class for Person.

```
public class PersonList extends ArrayList<Person> {

public PersonList() {
    super();
}

//our list only stores unique elements
@Override
public boolean add(Person person) {
    return !this.contains(person) && super.add(person);
}

//person iterator
public PersonIterator personIterator() {
    return new PersonIterator(this);
}
}
```

Finally my way to implement the iterator pattern.

```
public class PersonIterator implements Iterator<Person> {
private int index;
private Mode mode;           //iteration mode
private List<Person> origin; //ref to the input list
private List<Person> temp;   //used to store sublist 

//iteration mode
private enum Mode {
    NORMAL,
    YEAR,
    CITY
}

//constructor, the default mode is normal
public PersonIterator(PersonList list){
    mode = Mode.NORMAL;
    index = 0;
    origin = list;
    temp = new ArrayList<>();
}

//set to normal mode
public void normalMode(){
    index = 0;
    mode = Mode.NORMAL;
}

//set to year mode
public void yearMode(int year){
    index = 0;
    mode = Mode.YEAR;
    temp.clear();
    for(Person p: origin){
        if(p.getDOB().getYear() == year){
            temp.add(p);
        }
    }
}

//set to city mode
public void cityMode(String city){
    index = 0;
    mode = Mode.CITY;
    temp.clear();
    for(Person p: origin){
        if(p.getAddress().getCity().equals(city)){
            temp.add(p);
        }
    }
}

//
@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    if(mode == Mode.NORMAL){
        return index < origin.size();
    }
    else{
        return index < temp.size();
    }
}

@Override
public Person next() {
    if(mode == Mode.NORMAL){
        if(!this.hasNext()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        Person p = origin.get(index);
        index++;
        return p;
    }
    else{
        if(!this.hasNext()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        Person p = temp.get(index);
        index++;
        return p;
    }
}
}
```

It has several iteration mode for different criteria. The normal mode just traverses through the list, nothing more. The other mode, year mode for instance, adds all perons who were born in that year into the temp sublist, and then traverses this temp sublist normally.

To add more mode:

1. create a mode in enum
2. create a "xMode" method, and define how to fill the temp sublist

I tested the implamentation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person john = new Person.PersonBuilder("110", 1980, 8, 2, "john")
            .phone("120")
            .address("1000", "5th", "ave", "11F", "New York", "NY", 11345)
            .workAddress()
            .addFVA(null)
            .addFamilyMember(null)
            .build();

    Person adam = new Person.PersonBuilder("120", 1980, 11, 22, "adam")
            .phone("130")
            .address("31", "main", "st", "", "Stony Brook", "NY", 11411)
            .workAddress()
            .addFVA(null)
            .addFamilyMember(null)
            .build();

    Person lucy = new Person.PersonBuilder("130", 1978, 1, 3, "lucy")
            .phone("140")
            .address("1200", "6th", "ave", "2A", "New York", "NY", 11346)
            .workAddress()
            .addFVA(null)
            .addFamilyMember(null)
            .build();

    PersonList list = new PersonList();
    list.add(john);
    list.add(adam);
    list.add(lucy);
    PersonIterator i = list.personIterator();
    //normal iterator
    while(i.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(i.next().getName() + " is in the list");
    }

    //year mode, print out persons who were born in 1980
    i.yearMode(1980);
    while(i.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(i.next().getName() + " was born in 1980");
    }

    //city mode, print out persons who live in New York City
    i.cityMode("New York");
    while (i.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(i.next().getName() + " lives in NYC");
    }
```

Here is the result.

```
john is in the list
adam is in the list
lucy is in the list
john was born in 1980
adam was born in 1980
john lives in NYC
lucy lives in NYC
```

So my question is:

1. Is my approach a solution to the problem? 
   If not, please point out a better approac.
2. Is the code easy to read, easy to modify?
   If not, how to improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is a bit overkill, and not very efficient. Most of the things you need are already provided by the Java Core APIs. So I have following suggestions:

1- Instead of extending `ArrayList<Person>` and overriding the add method for uniqueness, consider using `java.util.Set`. If you need to keep the insertion order, use `LinkedHashSet<Person>`, otherwise simply go with `HashSet<Person>`. Subclassing a collection is most of the times not a good idea.

2- What you are trying to achieve is simply filtering, and this can be done simply&elegantly using Java 8's stream API. Instead of creating a custom iterator, simply use `filter` operation of stream api. Something like:

```
people.stream().filter(person -> person.getBirthYear() == 1980).forEach(person -> System.out.println(person.getName() + " was born in 1980"));
```

or if you want to collect them in a new collection, let's say, to a new, unordered set:

```
people.stream().filter(person -> person.getBirthYear() == 1980).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

You can chain multiple filters:

```
people.stream().filter(person -> person.getBirthYear() == 1980).filter(person -> "New York".equals(person.getAddress().getCity())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Thank you. Processing data with streams is very neat and elegant in java 8; but since the problem explicitly says to use iterator pattern, I need to create an universal filtering method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Reflection

```
public boolean matchesCriteria(Person p, String value, Object tester) {
    Field f = p.getClass().getDeclaredField(value);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Object o = f.get(p);
    if(o.equals(tester)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can call it by using a for loop to switch over all of the Person classes in a list and check for the valued

```
DOB dob = new DOB(//However you create a DOB in the year 1980);
for(Person p : pList) {
    if(matchesCriteria(p, DOB, dob) {
        System.out.println(p.getName(), "Was born in the year 1980");
    }
}
```

Will return all people born in the year 1980. You can change some things around to make it fit the method, or change the method to your liking.

This will get the Specific field in your Person class, Make sure (if it's private) to make it accessible outside of the class, and get its value. The code will then check if the two objects are the same, and return the boolean.

An example is if you had a field labeled "age": (Just to show how the code works with variables I know. Since I don't know how you have a MyYear created)

```
private int age;

for(Person p : pList) {
    if(matchesCriteria(p, "age", 9) {
        System.out.println(p.getName(), " is 9 year(s) old.");
    }
}
```

This makes matchesCriteria(Person, String, Object); universal to ANY field you have inside of the Person class.